# History of Raetia between 15 CE to 550 CE

Tags: ancient-rome, celts, population, bavaria

I know most of the history of the area of Raetia (by which I mean the Roman province, today roughly resembling the states Bavaria and Baden-Württemberg) from the first sources we have until today, except for the time from 15 - 550 CE.

This area used to be settled by Celts, but most of them migrated for some reason (Germanic raids?) before the Romans conquered it. I read that most Romans there were Foederati garrison troops.

What I would like to know is, what happened? Did Rome make no attempts to settle this area? If they did, with who? How did the population change after they retreated from the northern Limes? Did all the Romans (including the Romanized Celtic population) retreat?

Basically I would just like to get as much information about this period as we have available to us.

---

**Researched sources:**
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raetia
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limes#Upper_Germania_and_Rhaetia
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Bavaria
(other similar sources about the Goths, Vindelici, etc.)
Several books about Bavarian history (I forgot the exact titles)

Comment: This  may be too broad.

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace I doubt that there is too much information on this timeline (even if it's quite big), which is why I believe that a valid answer is possible.

Answer (score 1):

At least for half of your time frame since (from mid of the 3rd century) it were the Alemanni 
see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alemanni

Before maybe the Suebi 
see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suebi